# How to replace ajax response text with original text?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I get the ajax response, which is replacing the original text `if the checkbox is checked`. But how to do the opposite? Replace the response with original text if the user has unclicked the checkbox?

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'index.php?r=recommendations/entry/text',
   success: function(response) {
       if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
           recommendationText.html(response);
       }
   },
});
```

Comment: `else { recommendationText.html( "Original Text" );  }`

Comment: post your `HTML and JavaScript` code that may explore us more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you original text always the same ?

In that case, a simple `if else` could do the job :

You can execute a different statement in case the original `if` expression evaluates to `FALSE`

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'index.php?r=recommendations/entry/text',
   success: function(response) {
       if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
           recommendationText.html(response);
       } else { 
          recommendationText.html("Lorem ipsum"); 
       }
   },
});
```

Otherwise, you can store your original text in a variable :

```
var originalText;
originalText  = $("#your_element").text()
```

You can use you variable like this :

```
else { 
      recommendationText.html(originalText); 
}
```